# Performing a big task and relaying results to client AND cache. Should I use Celery?

Tags: python, django, celery, amqp

I'm developing an application with Django. Part of my application that I am designing is supposed to take a keyword, pull a bunch of data using various APIs and scrapers, and then display and then send that data to the client in the form of the table. Obviously I am caching all of this for performance reasons.

**I don't fully grok Celery yet, and would like to know if this is the best way to handle this task. I need to cache all of this into a database, so should I use an AMQP result backend, or a database result backend?**

Also, **what would be the best way send status updates on the task to the client (browser)?** If possible I would like to be able to send incremental results to the client so that the data being worked on appears as it is processed.

Comment: In general, I think the AMQP backend is better if you're expecting more traffic. That's what I've heard. As for sending incremental results to the client, are you looking to do that in real time? If so, perhaps look into Twisted. I haven't used it myself, but it's non-blocking and handles events asynchronously.